# Laravel Pusher not making any logs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, backend, pusher

I'm new to using laravel pusher I've followed the documentation and watch some tutorials on how to use it but somehow I cant get it work. I'm using laravel 5.6 on, php7.1 and nginx.

I've added all the pusher keys in my .env file already, below are some of my codes

**.env**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
```

**web.php**

```
use App\Events\TestEvent;

Route::get('/test', function() {
    event( new TestEvent() );
});
```

**broadcasting.php**

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'encrypted' => true,
    ],
],
```

**TestEvent.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = ['name' => 'Test User', 'email' => 'testuser@mail.com'];
        $this->message = 'Hello world';
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('TestChannel');
    }
}
```

When I tried to access the route **/test** on my app I expected that Pusher debug console logs anything but it doesn't, even Pusher error log.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe check your Laravel logs for any error messages.

Comment: @Fjarlaegur it doesnt log any in laravel logs

Comment: Import this `use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;`

Comment: and than do this`class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow`

Comment: I recommend to not use the `Sync` driver in production tough. The solution suggested by @tayyab_fareed is useful for debugging, but doing this will execute the broadcast on the main thread instead of using background processes (so it will slow your complete request down). Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467680/laravel-queues-how-sync-driver-works-does-it-executes-in-a-seperated-process)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with Pusher, so please correct me if i am wrong. But according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#broadcasting-events), you should fire `Events` implementing the `ShouldBroadcast` interface like this:

```
event(new TestEvent());
```

Care to explain why your event is using those traits? I dont see `Dispatchable` referenced anywhere. `InteractsWithSockets` is only stated as a `use` statement, not as trait. And as far as i can tell `SerializesModels` is only needed when trying to send a whole model as data in the event.

Comment: I've tried to fire an event using what you suggested but still no luck and as for those traits it's already included in the file/code (default) when you create an event

Comment: Take a look at your `config/Queue.php`. When you fire an event to broadcast, it is placed on a queue. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#broadcast-queue Maybe your queue is not correctly defined?

Comment: you are totally correct, the QUEUE_DRIVER is set to "database" and not "sync" and I forgot to run queue worker that's why it is not working. Thanks so much :)

Comment: No problem. Please read the comment from me on your post about the sync driver not really meant for production cases tough!

Answer (score 0):

setting up 'encrypted' => true, to 'encrypted' => false, in broadcasting.php works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Its not much clear from your code but you can have a look at `routes/channels.php` file.

Above file should have below mentioned code

```
Broadcast::channel('TestChannel', function () {
    # true can be replaced with condition in non-testing environment
    return true; 
});
```

In addition to this, you can also try replacing

`ShouldBroadcast` 
with 
`ShouldBroadcastNow` 
to obtain

`class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow`

Also add, 
`use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;`
under
`use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;`

`ShouldBroadcastNow` skips the queue and broadcasts your event message asap.